# AJAX Combobox button not displayed within the j query UI's tab

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-tabs

When i populate the combobox outside the tab of jquery UI it works fine. But when the same is done within the tab, the dropdown button of CB is not displayed and also the dropdown list is not visible. I'm new to using Javascript. can anyone help me in this regard.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>                          

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
</script>

         ............

    <div id="tabs-3">
         <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"  
            AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" DataTextField="display_name" 
            DataValueField="display_name" style="display: inline;" 
           AutoPostBack="True" MaxLength="0" Visible="true">

        </asp:ComboBox>


    </div>
```

Comment: +1. I had exactly the same problem. At the end I decided to get rid of it and use a normal DropDownList. Please, let me know if you figure out how to get it working. Cheers,

Comment: @aleafonso I'm sorry for now i didn't find a solution and I'm using the combobox within an ajax tab and it works fine. But I'll sure msg you if i find the reason :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this within your jQuery tabs look for the CSS file that contains the JQuery tabs styles.
Look for

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide
```

and change the

```
display: none
```

to

```
position: absolute; left: -10000px;
```

This worked for me by stopping the Inline Style on the asp/ajax/any control being put to 'display: none'